# Rootkit to hide a file on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

This is a bit of an odd question, but I'm making something of a puzzle for some friends to enjoy. The basic idea is that I have a Win 7 image with 8 (at the moment) keys on it. These keys are hidden in all sorts of interesting ways. For instance, I've filled up the `Links` folder with 10000 text files, each of the same size and made at the same time, only one of which has the right key. The key can be found because only one file contains letters (the keys are all 10-letter strings). Anyway, I'm getting a bit off-topic. I think it would be fun to hide one of the txt's with a rootkit and force my friends to use TDSSKILL or GMER to reveal it. Unfortunately, the only rootkit I have is hxdef (aka HackerDefender). It works great on XP, but it doesn't actually HIDE files on Windows 7 - it just makes them annoyingly hard to delete (as I found out the hard way). Anyone know of a good rootkit I can use in lieu of hxdef?

Requirements:

- Works on Win 7
- Can be configured to hide files (as well as itself) and processes (bonus points for ports)
- Lightweight (the VM should be as compact as possible)

Thanks!